# How to use After Effects Trim Path with an Illustrator Path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, mask, adobe-after-effects

I imported my Illustrator file into After Effects. I then turned the Vector layer into a shape layer. I added a trim path to the shape but the trim path does some weird start to end point mask.

Demonstration of my shape

[image: Demonstration of my shape]

My shape

[image: my shape]

**Question**: How would I set a trim path that would go from one end of the object to the other (start from the arrow and end at the other dot).

**Note**: When importing Illustrator files. Make sure each path/object is on a separate layer. When you're ready to import into After Effects, go to file -> import -> file. Make sure to change import as to **Composition - Retain Layer Sizes**. This will then import each layer so you can "create shape from vector layer" for each illustrator layer.

Comment: When I imported the AI file, I had all of my paths in one layer in Illustrator. This put all of the contents into the same layer in After Effects. Since I was going to create multiple trim paths, I needed to have each path use a separate trim path. To do this I put each path from Illustrator into its own layer. When you import using Composition - Retain Layer Sizes, After Effects keeps these layers separated. This edit was not necessary to the original question since I didn't ask about multiple paths using different masks but I thought the information was still useful.

Comment: To be serious, I think this is interesting for a maximum of 3 users here. Your upvote and all other upvotes are mine. Might be better to migrate to video.stackexchange.com...

Comment: I do agree with you. I am not always aware of the different sub stacks. I am not sure of what mods do for moving a question to a different stack once it has been answered but for future questions I will make sure to use video stack for editing video questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can use a trim path on a shape layer as track matte** to achieve a solid and smooth animation without keyframing a mask.

1. Bring your shape into After Effects:

   [image]
2. Make sure that no layer is selected in your composition and hit <kbd>G</kbd> to enable the **pen tool**
3. **Draw your animation path** from the bottom to the end of the shape

   [image]
4. Set the **contour width** of the new created shape layer to a value which covers the shape below
5. Set the fill color  to `None` by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking into the color field
6. If you roll out the shape layer by **clicking on the arrow**  <kbd>></kbd>  button left to the layer's name, there should be a appear another  <kbd>> Add</kbd>  Button in Track Mattes column. Click it to add a **Trim Paths** property
7. If *Trim Paths* is assigned to the shape layer go to your **last frame**, roll out **Trim Paths** property and click the stop watch of the **end value**, this should create a keyframe with a value of 100%.
8. Go to your first frame and set the **end** value to **0%** to get something like this:

   [image]
9. As last step set the **track matte** of the **solid layer below** to `Alpha`.

   [image]

Answer (score 5):

There are direction to paths! Who knew! If you are manually doing drawing the path in AI, follow the direction that you want the animation to work.

Now, for the this piece here I would put a solid on top. Use the pen tool to draw line that follows the your shape (middle not around) and then drop a stroke effect on it. You can then animate that to your liking. There is a way to do this with the path you have but the answer is off the top of my head

**EDIT:** Here is more of what I am talking about. Drop a shape layer, grab your pen tool. And mask around your shape. and then animate the points. The amount of points will determined by your animating style

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also set the lay that you are masking to track matte the layer that is animating the mask.

Comment: I do not want a stroke to replace the object with a drawn path in After Effects because of the endpoints if that is what you were suggesting. Do you know if it is possible to draw a path with the pen tool that will mask the shape? Then I can animate the path that is a mask to reveal the shape.

Comment: I've edited my comment above to do what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Confirmed. You can mask your object with the pen tool. Then animate that mask. You can add points as you go along, but AE doesn't animate the addition of points. Instead, it will add the point/s everywhere (and just tween the points as the animation progresses.)

Comment: to complete my comment :') Mask - M; pen tool - G; Add keyframe to Mask - Alt+Shift+M

Answer (score 1):

I think your animated mask mask should be something like the attached screenshoot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to have a simple line drawing that draws on with a trim path, this problem could be you've created the line using the Paint Brush tool. Go back into Illustrator, use the pen tool to create your shape line and you should be onto a winner!